# Find all patterns used in preg_* functions in PHP code

Tags: php, regex, phpstorm, code-search

I have around 4k PHP files. There are more than 6k preg_* functions used in the code.

I need to find all patterns used in the code and extract them. My aim is to group such patterns and replace them with a named constant.

I want to make a list like this: https://www.exakat.io/reports/codeigniter/datas/inventories_regex.html

I tried to make a regex search, but I'm not getting it right.

regex: https://regexr.com/48s1s

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Different IDEs could lead to different answers about how to approach this problem.

Comment: I am using PhpStorm

Answer (score 2):

The best tool I can think of for such task is [structural search in PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/structural-search-and-replace.html) (commercial software).

The main advantage is that it treats this kind of search as *code*, so it is much more discerning than regex or other search pattern that can only process *text*.

So you can do something like `$function$($pattern$,$argument$,$anotherargument$)`, set filter on function to match multiple functions, and set search to capture pattern part.

Comment: I have never used that. Thanks for the pointers. When I try to search with what you suggested, I get all the function listings, but how do I export all the patterns?
[![Please see this screenshot][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yChz.png

The export option exports all search results, I just want the patterns to be exported.

Comment: Hm hm, not sure if there is a way to be that precise with export, sorry. :( I guess this doesn't satisfy extraction part of your needs then.

Comment: I think you best go here is do use Find in Path to find all `preg_*` functions, then place a caret on a pattern, invoke context menu > refactor > extract > variable. PhpStorm would automatically replace it with a var of your preference. You can then refactor vars into constants later on. The downside is you would have to do that manually. But I guess it's Ok since you would still have to create constants for each of patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the variations of those patterns, I would recommend using "Find and Replace" of an IDE, for example with [Atom](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/find-and-replace/) or [Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/replace-in-files?view=vs-2017)

- find a preg_* function in your codebase
- extract the used pattern into a constant
- find the pattern in your files
- replace it with the defined constant

It might be quite some manual work, but you'll be able to do it step by step